# Plotting a random but continuous line

Tags: continuity, graphing-functions, random

Hopefully my question makes sense. I would like to generate a function which is continuous at all points. The use of the word "random" is somewhat of a misnomer, since it is not truly random. It must be random within constraints, chiefly being, I assume, that each point cannot "create" a discontinuity. However, this reasoning is circular, and I can't find a way to either:

1. Describe such a function mathematically
2. Generate a list of points programmatically

My biggest issue so far seems to be a way of checking continuity. My intuition is that, in a set of sets containing randomly generated points, there must exist a set where the points form continuous lines. If I can check each set of lines for continuity, I  would eventually find a "random" function.

Any thoughts on how best to move forward, or errors in my logic, are much appreciated! Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "all points are continuous"?

Comment: Huh? Aren't all lines continuous?

Comment: @ClementC. What I probably should have said, to be more clear, is that if my random points are a function of x, each point is continuous as defined by the traditional calculus method ($\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$). That being said, I am not treating the points as discrete.

Comment: @1110101001 You're correct, that's not the correct terminology. I actually meant a function of x.

Answer (score 0):

I think question's usage of the word continuous and discontinuous conflicts with the precise mathematical meaning the words... I believe you mean that you wish to generate a random set of points that *would lie upon a line.* In that case, you need to generate a set of points that adhere to

$$y=mx+b$$

Define some $m$ and $b$. Then loop a random number generator to create an array for $x$ for however many points you want. Apply the above definition for $y$, and you ought to have your random set of points $(x,y)$ that lie on a specific line.

If you wish to have a random set of points that lie on a *random* line, you first need to randomly generate $m$ and $b$.

Comment: I think you're right, however in the opposite way... I am trying to be very precise in my usage of continuous and discontinuous -- I want a non-discrete function of x, with no cusps or other discontinuities. I'm not doing a very good job of phrasing my question, but I was thinking more of something like a function where each value is random, but not in such a way as to create any discontinuity in the overall function. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: I don't follow. Why would a line have cusps or discontinuities? Also - and now I'm unsure if this is related - a computer fundamentally cannot create a continuous set of points and store it in memory. Computation is discrete.

Comment: As I clarified in the above comments, I actually used the wrong term there: I should've said function. And you're completely right, of course, computation is discrete. However, if I have some point $a$, and want to calculate the "next" point $b$, I can approximate to a degree the range of values $b$ can have such that no cusps (see a [previous question](http://tinyurl.com/zlzqznh) of mine) are formed, for example (subject to time, hardware, and other constraints). Such a function (if it exists) could only truly be described mathematically, any computation would be approximate.